# How can I import AutoCAD 3D solids into ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, autocad, 3d-analyst, 3d-model

I have an AutoCAD drawing that contains contours and 3D solids.  I am able to import the contours (which i don't need) but not the 3D solids (which I do need).  I understand ArcGIS does not support AutoCAD 3D solids but is there a workaround workflow to do this?

EDIT:
It was pointed out that this type of file should be supported in version 9.3.  I can confirm that ESRI Help for 10.1 states that polygon and multipatch solid and 3D face [is supported "on paper" in version 10.1 as well.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00100000007v000000)

However in the dxf I have solids are ignored in ArcGIS (ArcScene or imported) but it can be opened in AutoCAD, DWG TrueView 2013, SketchUp 8.

DWG TrueView 2013:
[image]

ArcScene 10.1:
[image]

Comment: Should be supported from 9.3 - http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Supported_AutoCAD_entities_and_MicroStation_elements

Comment: I am using 10.1 and the solid is not coming in. I will edit the question.

Comment: I can confirm that solids seem not to be read into ArcGIS although it is stated that they should ([up-to-date reference](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/cad/supported-autocad-and-microstation-geometry.htm))

Answer (score 2):

I ended up saving the model as DEA (Collada) in SketchUp Pro 8 then importing it into ArcGIS and using the Spatial Adjustment toolbar to georeference the model into position (using the drawing footprint for reference)  One important item - Spatial Adjustment does not seem to work on Geodatabase Multipatch features. I was only able to use Spatial Adjustment tools after I converted the model to Shapfile Multipatch.